# Selecting Overlapping / Touching regions (Binary Images, Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to select overlapping/ touching images from 2 binary images. The first image (blue circles) has the main body and I want to find any green triangles attached to it.

1st Binary Image here (colored for identification)
[image: 1st Binary Image]

2nd Binary Image here
[image: 2nd Binary Image]

```
FinalImage = BinaryImage1 | BinaryImage2;

**Apply Filter**
```

Expected result:
[image: Filtered Images]

Note how the unattached Green triangles are removed, & all blue circles are retained.

Is there a way to do this trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This calls for a morphological reconstruction! In morphological reconstruction, you specify a marker and start reconstructing the original image from that marker point using a morphological dilation.

Luckily for us, MATLAB already has a function for that, called [`imreconstruct`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imreconstruct.html) in the Image Processing Toolbox, which is called by `imreconstruct(marker,image)`

To recognize touching, but non-overlapping figures, we can just do a dilation on one of the input image to make touching figures overlap. As structuring element we can e.g. use a 3x3 square, so we also recognize 8-connected figures. After that we use the overlapping points as markers and do the morphological reconstruction using the combined image.

```
dilatedImage1 = imdilate(binaryImage1, strel('square',3));
finalImage = imreconstruct(dilatedImage1&binaryImage2, dilatedImage1|binaryImage2);
```

As you write that all circles, i.e. all parts from `binaryImage1` should be retained, we can just add `binaryImage1` to the result using

```
finalImage = finalImage | binaryImage1;
```

For your two example images, this results in:

[image: final image]

The circle on the upper right is not connected to any triangle. I don't know how that triangle appeared in your expected result image, but I suppose this is only for demonstration purposes.

<sub>Note: I imported the .jpg example images in MATLAB, which lead to ugly borders, so I did a morphological opening on the images first. The borders are still not optimal, but it doesn't look that bad.</sub>

Comment: Ah yes, sorry for the confusion; I was drawing a quick and simple example in MS Paint. Thank you!